# Expo app not updating app icon after file change | SDK 49

Tags: react-native, expo

After this last update no matter what I try it doesn't show up in expo go, expo website and not even in the apk/ipa binaries.

It's so frustrating, issue ticket have been opened on github nobody is addressing the issue

I've built a new app app just to make sure, same issue

This is built with create-expo-app